# Heuristics for the Hawking mass

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, mass

I have the following definition of [Hawking Mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_energy). Given a spacelike 2-surface $S$ embedded in a 3+1-dimensional Lorentzian Manifold $L$,

$$
M(S) := \sqrt{ \frac{\text{Area}(S)}{16 \pi}} \left(1- \frac 1 {16 \pi}\int_S H^2 d_{\sigma_S}\right),
$$
where $\sigma_s$ is the induced volume form on the surface $S$, $H$ is the mean curvature of the immersion $S \to L$.

From a heuristic point of view, I see how the second term can arise, as it encodes for an average of the rate of change of the area of $S$ when 'moved' in null directions. I would like to understand a formal way of saying this, if any.

My ultimate aim is to understand what the Hawking mass measures. Also, I'd like to understand if there is a relation with the [ADM mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism).

Answer (score 3):

A small  note on the definition. It should be

$$
M(S) := \sqrt{ \frac{\text{Area}(S)}{16 \pi}} \left(1- \frac 1 {16 \pi}\int_S \theta^-\theta^+ d_{\sigma_S}\right),
$$

where $\theta^\pm$ are the divergences along the two null directions. It is equal to what you have written if the 2-surface $S$ lies in a space-like 3D submanifold with vanishing extrinsic curvature.

The Hawking mass is one of the quasilocal energies and it measures the energy within $S$. But there are a number of qualification to be made and I am not sure how well it is understood. It is certainly above my head.

If the space-time is flat at spatial infinity and the 2-surface is a coordinate sphere, then as the radius goes to infinity the Hawking mass will approach the ADM mass.

Comment: A couple of trivial comments and questions on what has been said (just to put down my thoughts). Is there any sort of positive mass theorem for the Hawking Mass? It also seems that the mass is comparatively smaller when the surface is 'trapped', like in the inside of a Schwarzschild black hole. On the other hand, it is comparatively 'bigger' outside the black hole. How do these regions differ in 'energy'? Also, what would be the infinitesimal version of the mass here?

Comment: http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrr-2009-4/ I haven't read it, but it might be helpfull.

Comment: Nice reference, I was not aware of it.

Comment: @MBN Hello, I asked a similar question in [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4819130/equivalent-definition-of-hawking-quasi-local-mass). Could you please spend a moment looking into it? I was wondering why your definition takes a form that is somewhat different from mine and why my definition speaks of convergence instead of divergence. Thank you very much.